# Stackoverflow during async TCP read

Tags: c#, tcp

Finally a fitting problem for this website.

I have a .NET TCP server. This is my first server and it's working well. Client's join, are managed, and can join chat rooms etc. However, after about 30 minutes of time, with one client established, I get a System.StackOverflowException during NetworkStream.ReadAsync. I am completely unaware of what the issue is. It happens every time.

Here are the important details about my TCP Server's Client class, in which a new Client is created when a client joins.

```
    public class Client {

        public TcpClient tcpClient;

        public NetworkStream stream;

        public CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        private StringBuilder receiveString = new StringBuilder();


        public Client(TcpClient tcpClient) {
            this.tcpClient = tcpClient;
            this.stream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();
        }

        public void StartReadAsync(){
            ReadAsync(cts.Token);
        }

        private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken ct) {
          // Stackoverflow exception occurs on next line after 20-30 mins
            int amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, ct);
            if (amountRead > 0) {
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBuffer, 0, amountRead);
                receiveString.Append(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Client " + name + " sent: " + message);

                if (receiveString.ToString().IndexOf(eof) > -1) {
                    // Full message received, otherwise keep reading
                    if (OnClientRead != null)
                        OnClientRead(this, new SocketEventArgs(this, receiveString.ToString()));
                    receiveString.Clear();
                }
            }
            ReadAsync(ct);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the lifetime of this object?  If there are multiple object that are created and deleted you may have a problem with releasing of the physical resources that the TcpClient uses

Comment: While I can have multiple clients, this occurs with just one client connected. Furthermore, the client can disconnect (I don't handle it right now) and this will still eventually occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a re-entrant call, ReadAsync calls again ReadAsync, so yes, you will end witrh an StackOverflow exception.

Change your code to this:

```
public class Client 
{

    public TcpClient tcpClient;

    public NetworkStream stream;

    public CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];

    private StringBuilder receiveString = new StringBuilder();


    public Client(TcpClient tcpClient) {
        this.tcpClient = tcpClient;
        this.stream = this.tcpClient.GetStream();
    }

    public async void StartReadAsync(){

        while(await ReadAsync(cts.Token));
    }

    private async Task<bool> ReadAsync(CancellationToken ct) 
    {

        try
        {
            int amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, ct);
            if (amountRead > 0)
            {
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readBuffer, 0, amountRead);
                receiveString.Append(message);
                Console.WriteLine("Client " + name + " sent: " + message);

                if (receiveString.ToString().IndexOf(eof) > -1)
                {
                    // Full message received, otherwise keep reading
                    if (OnClientRead != null)
                        OnClientRead(this, new SocketEventArgs(this, receiveString.ToString()));
                    receiveString.Clear();
                }

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch { return false; }

    }
}
```

Comment: `while(await ReadAsync(cts.Token));` This line doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: It does, it will loop executing ReadAsync while you receive data, it's just an empty while. FYI, it will do the same as this but with less code: bool execute = true; while(execute){ execute = await  ReadAsync(cts.Token); }

Comment: Oops I missed the async modifier in StartReadAsync. Thanks, this works great. Although, I would never hit the `return false` (not within the catch {} ) correct?

Comment: It will, if you cancel the token or the connection gets broken.

Comment: Right! Wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: A tip, you can also add an event, something like public EventHandler ClientClosed; and execute it after the while(), in this way you can safely destroy any resources you have associated to this connection in your main server ;)